# String sum jasper

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have data in field 20:

```
200.000
10.000 
5.000 
1.000
```

in a string, how can I tell jasper soft studio to sum them? I tried creating a variable, with the expression Double.parseDouble ($F{field20})

I want to sum them that and print it in the right format, 216.000 in this case.

Comment: What value is in $F{field20}?

Comment: @Varun, the numbers I mentioned before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bad idea even though you can make it work. You should always store data in the most appropriate type. Make `field20` a number and then employ summation on the field.

If you cannot change the type of `field20` then make the field class expression a number e.g. `Double.valueOf(field20)`, create a Number variable (say `sum`) with initial value expression of 0 and variable expression of `$V{sum} + Double.valueOf(field20)`. `$V{sum}` then will hold the summation value you need.

Comment: your code was compilable but I didn't get the sum... I got a weird number 0123.0100.060.060.060.060.060.040.040.0

Comment: That looks like a String concatenation. You must be still passing String arguments instead of Number arguments.

Comment: I did this $V{sum}+Double.valueOf($F{field18}.replaceAll(".","")) to solve that concatenation problem but it doesn't compile

Comment: i tested this expression $F{field18}.replaceAll(".","") to see what I would get but the . didn't disappear

Comment: replaceAll takes a regex argument and the dot "." stands for any character thus replaceAll(".","") replaces every character in a string with an empty string. You should not replace the separator with an empty String anyway - you might change the order of the number. These are exactly the problems you are bound to get if you are using the wrong types. I suggest you follow my original advice and make field20 a Number.

Comment: I took your advice and casted field20 to Integer and it worked, not really what I wanted but will do the trick